# Best way for a Docker container to work with huge shared drive

Tags: docker, filesystems

I am building an application in a docker container, that in the end will have to read from a filesystem that is quite large (terabytes) in size.

The application itself will be running on another device.

I am now wondering which is better to use for connecting the container to this filesystem, a **volume** or a **bind mount**?

*Only read below if you want to hear more detailed reasoning from me*

The documentation for the volume state, if I read them correctly, that the content of the volume will be in a place on the host system which docker has access to. This makes me think that when I use a volume, Docker will try to place a copy of the really large filesystem on the shared drive, somewhere on the device that the application will be running on.

The bind mount documentation says that the information will be stored anywhere on the host system. This seems to indicate to me that the original information will remain on the shared drive, without creating any copies. But several other questions on this site have stated that the performance of the bind mount is a lot worse than the volume.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know the location on the host system you want to use, you should use a bind mount.

```sh
docker run -v /mnt/very-large-device:/data ...
```

With a named volume, the storage is in space Docker controls, usually inside `/var/lib/docker/volumes` on a native-Linux host or inside the hidden VM on other systems.  You can't (easily) control where the underlying storage actually is.  (You could configure the system to have the entire Docker installation on the large disk, or use extended volume options to create a named volume that's actually a bind mount; both are more complicated than using Docker's native bind-mount option.)

> ... the performance of the bind mount is a lot worse than the volume.

This is principally true on non-Linux systems.  On native-Linux systems, bind mounts and named volumes should have identical performance, and that should be approximately the same as the container filesystem.  On non-Linux systems, though, Docker needs to bridge between the Linux system inside the hidden VM and the host's filesystem, and this can be slow depending on access patterns.

As will all performance questions, the best way to determine which thing will be fastest is to actually set up an experiment on your intended system and measure it.